# daily vote limit

Tags: support

I understand we can cast up to 40 votes per day. (Vox populi badge =    Used the maximum 40 votes in a day )

How come that I cannot cast more than 39 votes on a single day? My profile says that I have cast 39 votes today, and I cannot cast another vote for the next 11 hours.

Answer (score 5):

The last 10 votes can only be cast on questions. From the [SO blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/):

> The daily vote limit used to be 30 votes per day; we’ve increased that to a maximum of 40 votes per day — but only if you vote on a combination of answers and questions.

Comment: Thanks. Where is that defined?? Is that info easily accessible? Why is it so hard to figure out the rules of this whole Stack Exchange?? This FAQ page http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits certainly does not mention that. -- and, of course, the SO FAQ says 30 votes per day, not 40. So, if GERMAN has a different set of rules, where can they be found? A lot of people here seem to be veterans who live an breathe the rules. But what about ppl who are new to the concept? The docu sucks!

Comment: @teylyn: It's terribly obscure. I only know how some things work by hanging around on meta and watching people complain about these hidden features. This is a fairly new feature, by the way.

Comment: @teylyn: I added a link to an official statement about this feature.

Comment: @teylyn This site does not have a different set of rules. This recent change is *not* yet widely documented because it affects *very* few people; Few use all their votes. The blog covers the major announcements; The [feature change list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) is for people who are interested in more obscure detail. But this forum is here to listen to your suggestions for improvement.

Comment: It's not the 10 last votes, which have to be on questions, but just 10 of 40.

Answer (score 1):

The site aims for a ratio of at least one vote on questions for every three votes on answers.

The limit used to be 30 votes a day. To encourage votes on questions, the limit was raised to 40 votes a day, but only if you observe the one to three ratio (or better) on questions. That is, of your forty votes, at least ten must be on questions, with the difference for answers.

When the system capped you at 39, you had voted on 30 answers and 9 questions, and your 40th vote was on a answer. If you had changed that vote to one on a question, the system would have accepted your 40th vote.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be true. I had recently reached the point where the system told me *you have X votes left* three times, with X plus my votes already given summed up to a number between 31 and 39. When I then voted on questions, the counter still decreased and after seeing a message like *no more votes today* I was not able to vote on a question either, staying at 30+ votes (less than 40)

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: I spoke about how the system works "in theory." Apparently, there are a few glitches so that it doesn't always work in practice.